# How to make HTML5 Builder to use my own copy of Android SDK

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, html5builder

I am using Embarcadero's HTML5Builder for Android mobile apps development.  If I install `android-setup.exe`, I may deploy the HTML5Builder project to android virtual device without problem.

Next, I uninstall `android-setup.exe` and set `path` variable to add my own copy of Android SDK path.  I then repeat the above steps to deploy the HTML5Builder project to android virtual device.  The IDE prompt me "Android SDK not installed".

Is that possible to make H5B to use my own version of Android SDK?

Comment: no more idea about your question but I think you should use eclipse and here also using android sdk you can use HTML5 for Android

Comment: docwiki.embarcadero.com said that: "your will need the latest version of the SDK Tools and Platform Tools, and the Android 4.0.3 (API15) SDK package". Did you check?

Comment: Yes. I have the latest SDK Tools and Platform (15) but it is in my own folder instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk` as I uninstall the Embarcadero's android SDK.

Comment: If you're using NTFS you could set up a [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) to point to your directory.

Comment: @TOndrej: Can I uninstall Android SDK and Platform tools completely from my system before I setup a junction to point to my directory?  I did try to clone whole Android SDK folder, uninstall Android SDK and copy back the Android SDK folder to %ProgramFiles% but H5B still report error.

Comment: @Chau Chee Yang: Could it be that H5B be looking for a registry entry to point to where the Android SDK are installed?

Comment: @NicholasRing: This is what I hope so but I couldn't spot the registry item related to Android SDK path.

Comment: @Chau Chee Yang: Have you tried [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to see what H5B is looking for?

Comment: @NicholasRing. Thanks. I found out the answer and post the answer too.

Comment: I left last bit of work. I post a new question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672535/manual-installed-android-sdk-tools-virtual-device-doesnt-work-in-embarcaderos]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make Embarcadero HTML5Builder works with manual installation of `Android SDK Tools`, follow these steps:

1. Set an environment variable `Path=%Path%;[android sdk tools]\sdk\platform-tools`
2. For Windows x86, create a registry key in `HKLM\Software\Android SDK Tools\Path = [android-sdk-path]\sdk`
3. For Windows x64, create a registry key in `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Android SDK Tools\Path = [android-sdk-path]\sdk`